docker failed to install the coturn server
I use this command to install coturn server,throw this error,why?
docker run -d -p 3478:3478 -p 3478:3478/udp -p 5349:5349 -p 5349:5349/udp -p 49152-65535:49152-65535/udp coturn/coturn
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint flamboyant_swartz (a95661813f6a8d1ddc39be917115c34460fb27db24a42c9e5cfc6259534c3671): Error starting userland proxy:.
ERRO[0016] error waiting for container: context canceled
but i use docker ps -a can find created container, then i try docker start 37 to start the container,throw new error:
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint flamboyant_swartz (3a9e3b86ed862df491dc8d1d02b68376938f4b28aa683c72aca58843135f8aeb): Error starting userland proxy:
Error: failed to start containers: 37
I try this methods to resolve the problem:

restart docker service
Find a port that conflicts with the host


Hi, welcome. I tried your command, and it eats all my ram in two seconds, hanging my machine. However, please read formatting help. Thank you
